# map do not appear on google maps javascript api v3

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps-api-3

Im am new to google maps api, and I'm trying to create my first map, by copying the example google gives you, but somehow, it isn't working.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <style type="text/css">
      html { height: 100% }
      body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 }
      #map_canvas { height: 100% }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript"
      src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=<MYKEY>&sensor=true">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function initialize() {
        var mapOptions = {
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
          zoom: 8,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
            mapOptions);
      }

    </script>
  </head>
  <body onload="initialize()">
    <div id="map_canvas" style="width:100%; height:100%"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I'm using a blog to test it, but when I publish the map doesn't appear. I am able to post text, but not the map. Ideas?

Comment: Could you post live link where map should appear?

Comment: [the code you posted works standalone](http://jsfiddle.net/42ytkyub/) (doesn't exhibit the issue).  It has something to do with how you are including it in the blog, which you haven't provided/described.

Comment: I still dont know why it didnt work in my blog, but anyway, I will use jsfiddle. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

first of all the google map api does not understand the css 100% of any div.

1. replace the 100% to static width and height
2. if you sure that
   the initialize() function is running on onload then its good if not
   try calling it with jquery on document ready function
3. if you are using jquery. dont forget to include
   your final code will be

javascript

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    function initialize() {
            var mapOptions = {
              center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
              zoom: 8,
              mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
                mapOptions);
          } initialize();
    });
```

and HTML

```
<div id="map_canvas" style="width:300px; height:300px"></div>
```

jsFiddle 
[googleMap](http://jsfiddle.net/0s0ynwyo/)

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
<script type="text/javascript"
  src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=<MYKEY>&sensor=true">
</script>
```

to

```
<script type="text/javascript"
  src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true">
</script>
```

or just provide the key parameter if you have

Comment: I have it with my key and it doesn't work. I have also tried what you have said, and still doesn't work